# Unclosed character class

Tags: regex, jenkins, build.xml

Iam using jenkins to build my project. I have written the following lines in my build.xml

```
<replaceregexp file="../BuildConfig/src/com/edutor/build/${TYPE}.java"  match="public static    
final String NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS[] = (.*)"  replace="public static final String 
NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS[] = ${MENU_LIST_ITEMS};" />
```

In jave file the variable syntax is as follows...

```
public static final String NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS[] =       
{"Messages","Tasks","Discussions","Stats","Notes","Apps","Profile","Settings"};
```

I want to replace the whole stmt with my desired stmt but when iam running getting error as follows..

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/K2_Learning_Build/IgnitorACE/build.xml:254: 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 56

public static final String NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS[] = (.*)
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: Complete guess; escape here: `NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS\[\]`

Comment: @AlexK. is right. It thinks `[]` is a character class, but an invalid one with no contents.

Answer (score 0):

Alex says you need to escape the brackets:

> escape here: NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS[]